# How to prove the extention of a vector field on the sphere minus one or two points is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a vector field $X$ which never vanishes on $S^2-\{(0,0,1\}-\{(0,0,-1\}$, I know that you can extend it to the whole sphere by putting $X(0,0,1)=X(0,0,-1)=0$ but I don't know how to prove the extension is smooth.

In particular I want to show this for the vector field given by 
$$X(p)=(-\sin(v)\cos(u),-\sin(v)\sin(u),\cos(v) ),$$
where $p=(\cos(v)\cos(u),\cos(v)\sin(u),\sin(v))$.

Comment: That extension is not smooth.  All around the bad points, the lengths of the vectors you've given are 1, so the extension is not even continuous.  You need to scale each vector so that their lengths tend to 0 as you approach the bad points.

Comment: thanks! I suppose I need to do the same for a vector field which is defined on the sphere minus only one point by using the stereographic projection right?

Comment: Scale the vectors so that near the undefined point their lengths are 0?  Exactly.  This is what you need to be able to set the vector at the bad point equal to 0 and have it be continuous.  To have it be smooth, you need to multiply by some smooth function that smoothly approximates 0 near the bad point; something like (p_z)-1, the z-coordinate of the point minus 1.